# Launching a .reg within a .bat file

Tags: date, batch-file, registry

So im trying to make life easier for my technicians as they sometimes forget to set certain thing on a newly formatted pc.

Ive managed to setup the power setting part of it, but im having trouble with the decimal symbols and date format. I have a Full export of the HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International exactly like i want it but im having trouble putting it into the current bat file as i don't REALLY want more than 1 file for them to run. So i thought it might be great if could put the registry value inside the batch file and maybe launch it as a seperate shell? i dono any advice would be great. Here is what i have so far.

Bat file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%G IN ('wmic os get Caption /value') DO SET _version=%%G 
echo %_version%

IF %_version%==XP (
POWERCFG /setactive "always on"
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /monitor-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /monitor-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /disk-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /disk-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /standby-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /standby-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /hibernate-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change "always on" /hibernate-timeout-dc 0
) ELSE (
POWERCFG /Change /monitor-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change /monitor-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG /Change /disk-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change /disk-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG /Change /standby-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change /standby-timeout-dc 0
POWERCFG /Change /hibernate-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /Change /hibernate-timeout-dc 0
)

pause
```

---

Registry value i want in the bat file:

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International]
"Locale"="00001c09"
"LocaleName"="en-ZA"
"s1159"="AM"
"s2359"="PM"
"sCountry"="South Africa"
"sCurrency"="R"
"sDate"="/"
"sDecimal"="."
"sGrouping"="3;0"
"sLanguage"="ENS"
"sList"="."
"sLongDate"="dd MMMM yyyy"
"sMonDecimalSep"="."
"sMonGrouping"="3;0"
"sMonThousandSep"=" "
"sNativeDigits"="0123456789"
"sNegativeSign"="-"
"sPositiveSign"=""
"sShortDate"="dd/mm/yyyy"
"sThousand"=" "
"sTime"=":"
"sTimeFormat"="hh:mm:ss tt"
"sShortTime"="hh:mm tt"
"sYearMonth"="MMMM yyyy"
"iCalendarType"="1"
"iCountry"="27"
"iCurrDigits"="2"
"iCurrency"="2"
"iDate"="2"
"iDigits"="2"
"NumShape"="1"
"iFirstDayOfWeek"="6"
"iFirstWeekOfYear"="0"
"iLZero"="1"
"iMeasure"="0"
"iNegCurr"="2"
"iNegNumber"="1"
"iPaperSize"="9"
"iTime"="0"
"iTimePrefix"="0"
"iTLZero"="1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need it in a batch file, try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal
for %%a in (
     "Locale=00001c09"
     "LocaleName=en-ZA"
     "s1159=AM"
     "s2359=PM"
     "sCountry=South Africa"
     "sCurrency=R"
     "sDate=/"
     "sDecimal=."
     "sGrouping=3;0"
     "sLanguage=ENS"
     "sList=."
     "sLongDate=dd MMMM yyyy"
     "sMonDecimalSep=."
     "sMonGrouping=3;0"
     "sMonThousandSep= "
     "sNativeDigits=0123456789"
     "sNegativeSign=-"
     "sPositiveSign="
     "sShortDate=dd/mm/yyyy"
     "sThousand= "
     "sTime=:"
     "sTimeFormat=hh:mm:ss tt"
     "sShortTime=hh:mm tt"
     "sYearMonth=MMMM yyyy"
     "iCalendarType=1"
     "iCountry=27"
     "iCurrDigits=2"
     "iCurrency=2"
     "iDate=2"
     "iDigits=2"
     "NumShape=1"
     "iFirstDayOfWeek=6"
     "iFirstWeekOfYear=0"
     "iLZero=1"
     "iMeasure=0"
     "iNegCurr=2"
     "iNegNumber=1"
     "iPaperSize=9"
     "iTime=0"
     "iTimePrefix=0"
     "iTLZero=1"
     ) do for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
        REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International" /v "%%~b" /t REG_SZ /d "%%~c" /f
        FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%d IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International" /v "%%~b" 2^>nul^| find "REG_SZ"') DO (
            IF NOT "%%~c"=="%%~e" ECHO ERROR reading "%%~e" IN %%b, "%%~c" is NOT SET
        )
    )
)
```

I added conrol code (`REG QUERY`) to read the registry after write the values.
Before running the code make a backup from the registry if needed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be changing the values in registry. Even when run as administrator

Comment: @user2728293 I added control code to read the registry back after writing the new values. If the value is not set, you get an error message. Please try it now.

Comment: :P Thx endoro. seems like my home pc is just weird.... but works 100% on my work pc! But thx for the effort! This REALLY helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can import a `.reg` file directly with `regedit`. Just launch `regedit /S yourfile.reg` in your batch file.

The `/S` hides the confirmation box.

See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php for details.